# Scrapy follow urls based on condition

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy and I want to extract each topic that has at least 4 posts. I have two separate selectors :

1. real_url_list in order to get the href for each topic
2. nbpostsintopic_resp to get the numbers of posts

   ```
   real_url_list = response.css("td.col-xs-8 a::attr(href)").getall()
   for topic in real_url_list:
       nbpostsintopic_resp = response.css("td.center ::text").get()
       nbpostsintopic = nbpostsintopic_resp[0]
       if int(nbpostsintopic) > 4: 
       yield response.follow(topic, callback=self.topic)
   ```

[image]

ULR : https://www.allodocteurs.fr/forums-et-chats/forums/allergies/allergies-aux-pollens/

Unfortunately, the above does not work as expected, the number of posts seems to not be taken into account. Is there a way to achieve such a condition ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line

```py
nbpostsintopic_resp = response.css("td.center ::text").get()
```

Note that this will always give you the same thing, there is no reference to your `topic` variable.

Instead, loop through `tr` selectors and then get the information from them

```py
def parse(self, response):
    for row in response.css("tbody > tr"):
        nbpostsintopic_resp = row.css("td.center::text").get()
        if int(nbpostsintopic_resp) > 4:
            response.follow(row.css("td > a")[0], callback=self.topic)
```